# How to use console.table() to see the store.load response?

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-chrome-devtools, extjs5

In a extjs5 grid, after store.load (), we can preview the grid load result with the chrome developer tools (Network » Preview / Response).

It is possible to build a preview / response with console.table()?

Something like: **console.table (store?? ["name", "email"])**

How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```
grid.getStore().on("load",function(){

console.table(grid.getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData);
});
```

Check out this working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xpe9V/1576/

**EDIT:**

Based on the fiddle from your comment (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/to2):

I think you forgot to also access the "items" value inside your data array like this:

```
console.table(gridA.getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData.items);
```

Check out this corresponding fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/to4

Comment: Thanks Lucian. Very good. However, my console table does not show the values but only the words array [3] in all columns. Any idea how to show the values (objects) that are within the arrays? Thanks

Comment: could you provide a fiddle to look at it ?

Comment: [FIDLLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/to2). For celerity, the fiddle has no code to filter the grid, just makes grid load in each combobox item selected

Comment: Thanks Lucian. Works great now.